# HTTP fetch request results in an extra failed OPTIONS request ("provisional headers are shown")

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, deployment, cors

I have a service that provides webhook endpoints, which are called via `fetch` from a web app. When running the web app locally, I see the normal `OPTIONS` preflight request, followed by a successful `GET` request.

[image: webhook request on localhost]

In production, I see that there are two `OPTIONS` requests, one that succeeds as normal, and a second one that fails. This is basically fine - the request succeeds and the webhook gets called as expected. However, I'm worried that the failed `OPTIONS` request is indicative of some kind of misconfiguration (plus it adds noise to the network inspector when debugging).

[image: webhook request on production]

[image: detail of failed webhook request]

The web app is running on AWS Amplify, and the webhook service is running on AWS ECR behind an application load balancer.

Any idea why I'm seeing the failed `OPTIONS` request?